# scatter plot in sas does not show

Tags: sas, scatter-plot

I am new in SAS and I'm trying to do scatter plot to see X vs residual but when I run the code this error appears 
ERROR: Procedure SQPLOT not found.
this is my code:

```
data EC
    input x e;
    datalines;
       2   3.2
       3   2.9
       4  -1.7
       5  -2.0
       6  -2.3
       7  -1.2
       8  -0.9
       9   0.8
      10   0.7
      11   0.5
    ;
    run;
    proc sqplot data = EC;
    scatter x = x y=residual;
    run;
```

could you help me where is the wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no procedure name SQPLOT.  You probably want to use SGPLOT.

```
data EC;
input x e;
datalines;
   2   3.2
   3   2.9
   4  -1.7
   5  -2.0
   6  -2.3
   7  -1.2
   8  -0.9
   9   0.8
  10   0.7
  11   0.5
;
run;
proc sgplot data=EC;
  scatter x = x y=e;
run;
```

For the situations where your code tries to use a procedure which is not licensed (or installed) the log will show a similar ERROR: message.